# Ubuntu 16.04.6 building driver gives missing header file error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, driver, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to build my serial port USB driver from C source using makefile but when I type sudo make or sudo make install, the output is like;

> sudo make
>
> gcc -Wall -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE
>   -I/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build/include -D__SMP__ -DSMP -I/usr/src/linux-4.15.0-45-generic/drivers/usb/serial/ -O   -c -o ftdi_sio.o ftdi_sio.c In file included from
>   /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build/include/linux/kernel.h:7:0,
>                    from ftdi_sio.c:251: /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build/include/linux/linkage.h:8:25:
>   fatal
>
> error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated. : recipe for target 'ftdi_sio.o'
>   failed make: *** [ftdi_sio.o] Error 1

I know asm/linkage.h file is not in include/linux directory. The problem is, how can I change the directory of given header file or how to replace header file to given directory. I'm also open for other solutions. Makefile and Rules.make files are;

Rules.make:

```
# -*-makefile-*-
#
# This file is part of the sample code for the book "Linux Device Drivers",
# second edition. It is meant to be generic and is designed to be recycled
# by other drivers. The comments should be clear enough.
# It partly comes from Linux Makefile, and needs GNU make. <rubini@linux.it>

# TOPDIR is declared by the Makefile including this file.
ifndef TOPDIR
    TOPDIR = .
endif

# KERNELDIR can be speficied on the command line or environment
ifndef KERNELDIR
    KERNELDIR := $(shell echo "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build")
endif
# The headers are taken from the kernel
    INCLUDEDIR = $(KERNELDIR)/include

# We need the configuration file, for CONFIG_SMP and possibly other stuff
# (especiall for RISC platforms, where CFLAGS depends on the exact
# processor being used).
ifeq ($(KERNELDIR)/.config,$(wildcard $(KERNELDIR))/.config)
    include $(KERNELDIR)/.config
else
    MESSAGE := $(shell echo "WARNING: no .config file in $(KERNELDIR)")
endif

# ARCH can be speficed on the comdline or env. too, and defaults to this arch
# Unfortunately, we can't easily extract if from kernel configuration
# (well, we could look athe asm- symlink... don't know if worth the effort)
ifndef ARCH
  ARCH := $(shell uname -m | sed -e s/i.86/i386/ -e s/sun4u/sparc64/ \
        -e s/arm.*/arm/ -e s/sa110/arm/)
endif

# This is useful if cross-compiling. Taken from kernel Makefile (CC changed)
AS      =$(CROSS_COMPILE)as
LD      =$(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
CC      =$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
CPP     =$(CC) -E
AR      =$(CROSS_COMPILE)ar
NM      =$(CROSS_COMPILE)nm
STRIP   =$(CROSS_COMPILE)strip
OBJCOPY =$(CROSS_COMPILE)objcopy
OBJDUMP =$(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump

# The platform-specific Makefiles include portability nightmares.
# Some platforms, though, don't have one, so check for existence first
ARCHMAKEFILE = $(TOPDIR)/Makefile.$(ARCH)
ifeq ($(ARCHMAKEFILE),$(wildcard $(ARCHMAKEFILE)))
  include $(ARCHMAKEFILE)
endif

USBDI=/linux

# CFLAGS: all assignments to CFLAGS are inclremental, so you can specify
# the initial flags on the command line or environment, if needed.

    CFLAGS +=  -Wall -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -I$(INCLUDEDIR)

ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    CFLAGS += -D__SMP__ -DSMP
endif

# Prepend modversions.h if we're running with versioning.
ifdef CONFIG_MODVERSIONS
    CFLAGS += -DMODVERSIONS -include $(KERNELDIR)/include/linux/modversions.h
endif

#Install dir
VERSIONFILE = $(INCLUDEDIR)/linux/version.h
VERSION     = $(shell awk -F\" '/REL/ {print $$2}' $(VERSIONFILE))
INSTALLDIR = /lib/modules/$(VERSION)/misc
```

Makefile:

```
# This Makefile has been simplified as much as possible, by putting all
# generic material, independent of this specific directory, into
# ../Rules.make. Read that file for details

# The usb serial headers
INCLUDEUSBSER := $(shell echo "/usr/src/linux-`uname -r`/drivers/usb/serial/")

TOPDIR  := $(shell pwd)
#TOPDIR = .
include $(TOPDIR)/Rules.make

CFLAGS += -I$(INCLUDEUSBSER) -O

OBJS = ftdi.o

all: $(OBJS)

ftdi.o: ftdi_sio.o
    $(LD) -r $^ -o $@

install:
    install -d $(INSTALLDIR)
    install -c $(OBJS) $(INSTALLDIR)

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core
```

I also have ftdi_sio.c file and ftdi.sio.h file which is I think not bounded with this problem.

Comment: The path `include/asm/linkage.h` is kernel 2.6 (or earlier.) A contemporary kernel has like `arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h`

Comment: So it seems i have to change all header files #include <...> tags in those directories manually. Do you have any suggestions for this situation. The driver I want to build seems a file structure like "include/asm/linkage.h" instead of arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h